# My Input Field Disappears and does not work unless I load a new scene and load the old scene back in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a customizable game using Unity 2019.3f. In my main menu, I have the option for people to input a number into an input field for the amount of ammo. The input field then converts that value to an int and sets a gameobject's transform position.x equal to it. For some reason, when I input a number into the input field and click apply settings, the input field completely disappears and I have to click Play and then go back to the main menu for the input field to reappear and then somehow start working and correctly assigning the right numbers to the right spots. I used Debug.Log to see if the value of the input field were convertible to an int but they were. My code to set the gameobject transform to the input field number is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GetInputValue : MonoBehaviour
{
   public InputField player1ammoinput;
   public InputField player2ammoinput;
   public GameObject ammo1;

   ammo1.transform.position = new Vector3(System.Convert.ToInt32(player1ammoinput.text), 0f, 0f);
   ammo1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(System.Convert.ToInt32(player1ammoinput.text), 0f, 0f);

   Debug.Log(player1ammoinput.text);
}
```

Can someone find out why unity is doing this? ammo1 is just the gameobject that stores the number. It is an empty Gamebject. The actual input field is a different gameobject which I refer to in this script as player1ammoinput.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you are parsing the text to an integer value, and then using that value to move the ammo1 object to the side (or towards the player).

I suggest moving the parsing to an extra variable before the actual adaptation, and think the value you get (say 22 ammo) will move the ammo1 item 22 units away, which is FAR, hence it disappears immediately from view.

Comment: ammo1 is just the gameobject that stores the number. It is an empty Gamebject. The actual input field is a different gameobject which I refer to in this script as player1ammoinput.